# Как определить какой класс будет присвоен указателю на базовый?

Tags: c++, ооп, rtti

Классы `ConsolIOManager` и `FileIOManager` являются публичными **наследниками** `IOManager`.

```
        IOManager *obj = nullptr;
        switch (Solution) {
        case ManualInput: {
            obj = new ConsolIOManager;
            break;
        }
        case InputFromFile: {
            obj = new FileIOManager;
            break;
        }
        }
        // тут нужно вызывать разные методы дочерних классов
        // в зависимости от инициализации указателя.
        // т.е если был выбран InputFromFile, я хочу сделать так:
        // obj->a();
        // иначе obj->b();
```

**Как определить какой класс будет присвоен указателю на базовый?**

Нет, делать это внутри `switch` я не хочу.

Comment: Применить `dynamic_cast`? Но, может, лучше перепроектировать так, чтобы вызывалась одна и та же виртуальная `a()`? :)

Comment: @Harry все функции так и вызываются, но есть одна, которую вызывать не нужно исключительно при InputFromFile

Comment: @Harry не могли бы Вы уточнить про dynamic_cast? Не понимаю как он тут поможет.

Comment: Тут скорее более уместен вопрос зачем?

Comment: @VTT Что конкретно "зачем"?

Comment: Зачем определять, какой класс был присвоен указателю на базовый? Или, если перефразировать, Почему для использования этого объекта недостаточно обращения к методам базового класса? Обычно это говорит о том, что либо структура классов с изъяном, либо что используется не правильно.

Comment: Классическая XY проблема. Правильный полиморфный дизайн не разрешает, чтобы еому-то было нужно вызвать для одного типа `a`, а для другого `b`. Править надо дизайн, а не заниматься ерундой с RTTI.

Comment: @VTT ТС мне не верит, думаете, поверит вам?... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
InputFromFile * iptr = dynamic_cast<InputFromFile*>(obj);
if (iptr) {
    // Значит, и в самом деле InputFromFile
}
```

Но еще и еще раз - если вам приходится прибегать к этому средству в своем коде - значит, на 99% вы плохо его продумали...

Answer (score 1):

По возможности стоит стараться у базового класса делать абстрактные методы, а в наследниках их . Тогда явно каст не нужен. 
Можно создать абстрактный метод ManagerType GetType() const у базового класса, который возвращает элемент перечислятеля. В наследниках его реализовывать return ManagerType::Console но это не очень хорошая практика, как и делать dynamic_cast со всем подряд пока он не вернёт не null, и любые другие явные переходы. Проблема будет, если понадобится создать нового наследника. Придётся ходить по всему коду в поисках таких конструкций, вспоминать давно написанный код (это в лучшем случае, а если его писал не ты? ) в попытках понять, что тут вообще происходит. В общем не делай так.